# Fixed effect tests

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have done a fixed effect regression after doing the Housman test. I am curious what tests should I use to see whether the results of regression are accurate.

Comment: Check the other model assumptions, see e.g. Wooldridge's introductory text book.

Answer (score 0):

The type of tests you might want depend somewhat on the type of regression you've done (e.g. linear, generalized linear (logistic, poisson, etc.)).

In linear regression, people often use the R2 as a measure of how much variance the data explains.  This is read as a proportion and can be thought like a percentage, e.g. if R2 = 0.7 ~ 'model explains 70% of the variance in the data'.

There are measures that apply to other types of regression, e.g. confusion matrices, or the C-statistics (Area Under the Receiver Operator Characteristic/AUC) for logistic regression.  The C-statistic can be intercepted in a similar way to the R2.

Steer clear of measures such as AIC if you want to know how 'accurate' you model is.  These are very useful for comparing similar models, but don't tell you how accurate they are.

I'd suggest plotting your observed and fitted values.  If it predicts well they should form a (fairly) straight line with little spread.  It's also worth plotting the fitted values and residuals (but read up about what residuals are).

I'd recommend the brilliant UCLA stats pages on the following link.  They have annotated examples of lots of regressions/analyses in a various stats programs including Stata, R and SAS.
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/annotatedoutput/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, info was very useful. I have done a fixed effect linear panel regression in stata. What I want to do is to run additional tests to check whether the regression is accurate. This is my first time with panel regression. For example when I did an OLS regression I run several tests (VIF,hettest and so on. I would like to know what similar tests are appropriate for fixed effect regression.

[image: Result of regression]